# can not delete database row using foreach loop - php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I trying to delete some data from  three tables,

1:- ailments
2:- jnctn_ailments_symptoms
3:- symptoms

I tried to delete the Link first from Junction Table, Then Delete The Ailment (vise versa too) and then final check the symptoms for any other link with another ailment, if not delete the symptom from symptom table.
 but I am failing at on step in foreach loop, I am checking the occurrences for symptoms beside the ailment deleted. everything is fine but when it comes to deleting the symptom I get mysql error " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1".

I the ids for the symptoms are retrieved successfully but not delete query not working, somehow.

please see the following code and let me know where I am mistaken.

```
if(isset($_GET['del']))
{
    $delID = $_GET['del'];



    $originalSymptoms="";
    $symptomO[] = array();
    echo $delID;
    $symp = "SELECT symptomID  FROM symptoms 
            INNER JOIN jnctn_ailments_symptoms
            ON jnctn_ailments_symptoms.FK_symptomID= symptoms.symptomID
            INNER JOIN ailments
            ON ailments.ailmentID = jnctn_ailments_symptoms.FK_ailmentID
            WHERE ailments.ailmentID IN ('".$delID."')";


    mysql_select_db($dbName);
    $sympRes = mysql_query($symp,$con) or die(mysql_error());

        while($symprow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sympRes))
             {
               if(empty($originalSymptoms))
               {
                $originalSymptoms = $symprow['symptomID'];
               }
                else
                {
                $originalSymptoms = $originalSymptoms.",".$symprow['symptomID']; 
                }
              }




   echo $originalSymptoms;


     $newSymptoms = explode("," , $originalSymptoms);
    foreach($newSymptoms as $symptom)
    {
    $originalSymptomsArray[] = $symptom;

    }
       echo count($originalSymptomsArray);

        $delAilment = "DELETE FROM ailments WHERE ailmentID='$delID'";
    $delAilmentResult = mysql_query($delAilment,$con) or die(mysql_error());

   $delLink = "DELETE FROM  jnctn_ailments_symptoms WHERE FK_ailmentID ='$delID'";
   $delLinkResult = mysql_query($delLink,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    foreach($originalSymptomsArray as $symptom)
    {
        echo $symptom."<br>";




        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM jnctn_ailments_symptoms WHERE FK_symptomID=".$symptom;
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2,$con);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result2);
        if(!$result2 || $result2 != 0)
        {
            echo mysql_error();
            $delSymptom = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $delSymptom = true;
        }


        if($delSymptom)
        {

            $sqlDel = "DELETE FROM symptoms WHERE symptomID ='$symptom'";
            $delResult = mysql_query($sqlDel,$con)or die(mysql_error());
            if(!$delResult)
            {
                echo mysql_error();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Symptoms Deleted!";
            }
        }




    }
```

I have tried FK_symptomID='$symotom'"; , concatenation etc, nothing worked.

Comment: Have you tried echoing your queries and seeing if they're valid?

Comment: I did and got something like following:SELECT * FROM jnctn_ailments_symptoms WHERE FK_symptomID=206 , it looks fine to me. what do you say?

Comment: That's one query, you've got at least a couple more. Echo them all and see what you're dealing with. Manually run those queries and see if they work.

Comment: they are working in mysql and they all are same, the complete query.

regards

Comment: Post the echoed delete query. PHP seems to think it has something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate all your queries mentioned as follows,

```
$sqlDel = "DELETE FROM symptoms WHERE symptomID ='".$symptom."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

somehow following code worked

```
 foreach($originalSymptomsArray as $symptom)
    {


        $sql2 = "SELECT `ID`, `FK_ailmentID`, `FK_symptomID` FROM `jnctn_ailments_symptoms` WHERE `FK_symptomID`='".$symptom."'";

        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2,$con);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result2);
        if($count>0)
        {
            echo mysql_error();
            $delSymptom = 0;
        }
        else
        {

            $delSymptom = 1;
        }


        if($delSymptom==1)
        {

            $sqlDel = "DELETE FROM symptoms WHERE symptomID ='".$symptom."'";
            $delResult = mysql_query($sqlDel,$con)or die(mysql_error());
            if(!$delResult)
            {
                echo mysql_error();
            }

        }




    }
```

thank you for concatenation suggestion, and thank you everybody.